# Get angular (9) component template data without initializing component

Tags: angular

We have made an help section in angular (currently version 9 with ivy). This section is built up using small components for every part of the help. One help page consists of one or many components.

One page do not contain all components though.

We would now like to have a search for the help section. The search should be able to detect hits in all text (raw html is fine) in all components html templates, including those that are not visible at the moment.

Is there any way to access the template data/html of an component if it is not currently being shown/instantiated?

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to search, not in the components per se, but in the data that the components are bound to.

That data should live in the top-level component, or in a service that all of the sub-components share.

If the action of searching is itself buried within a sub-component, which it probably is, you would typically have the search method live inside the shared service, and you would call it from your sub-component.

That would be the cleaner way.  If you're not using a service, but rather passing the data from the top-level component to the sub-components through input bindings, you will have to fire off an event from the search sub-component that the top-level component will subscribe to.

For more info, check out https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction and https://fireship.io/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/.

Comment: I do not think either of those solution would help us. First that solution would require the component to be initialized? And secondly that would also require the data to be accessible in the code part of the component. We would like to access text in div:s etc in the template of the component.

Comment: "We would like to access text in div:s etc in the template of the component" - to do that, your component(s) will still have to be initialized.  You're welcome to use various methods of reading the DOM (googling "angular search dom element" will get you started), although it's not really the Angular way, but those components will still have to exist in the DOM at the time of your search.  One thing to note is that the *ngIf directive will not render your component/html if what it's bound to is falsy. the [hidden] directive on the other hand still renders it, but sets display:none on it.

Comment: The reason for my original question was to find out if there are any way to access that information, without having to add it to the DOM first (images etc would be downloaded for no use then I guess, even with hidden). Since angular obviously have access to that information somehow I was hoping that there would be some kind of way to extract it from Angular without having to take the workaround to first add it to the DOM.
According to one of our developers this was possible before.

But thanks for the feedback.